# What is the difference between addProduct(_:_:) and addingProduct(_:_:)?

Tags: ios, swift, double

I've used both the methods and it results the same result. Can anyone explain whats the real difference is.

```
let num1 = 10.4
let num2 = 20.2
var result: Double = 20.1
result.addProduct(num1, num2) // 230.18
result.addingProduct(num1, num2) // 230.18
```

Comment: Example code is misleading, if you actually put `addProduct` before `addingProduct` you won't get `230.18` two times, because `addProduct` will modify `result`. But if `addingProduct` preceeds `addProduct` you will get same result both times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*addProduct* is the mutable version of *addingProduct* which just returns the addition.

```
var a: Double = 5
let result = a.addingProduct(2, 2) -> 'a' value is still 5, 'result' value is 9
a.addProduct(2, 2) -> 'a' value is 9 now
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at Apple document for these 2 methods.

[addingProduct(_: _:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2886213-addingproduct?changes=latest_minor)

> Returns the result of adding the product of the two given values to this value, computed without intermediate rounding.

[addProduct(_: _:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2298405-addproduct?changes=latest_minor)

> Adds the product of the two given values to this value in place, computed without intermediate rounding.

Answer (score 2):

addingProduct just return the product and does not change value, when addProduct does. 
addingProduct usable when you want to get result and not change variable itself:

> let product = a.addingProduct(num1, num2)

Now product has the result, “a” didn’t change

> a.addProduct( num1, num2)

Here value of a has changed